Sign in pop up appearing when access site after Windows Server updates
I am using IIS on a Windows Server virtual machine where my applications are deployed. Windows Server received the updates and it restarted after the updates finished. After the restart, When I accessed my site, a pop up appeared asking for a sign in. Pop up looked like below.

I checked SSL but it was not an issue. I checked authentication and the access to site and it was also not an issue. It is a common issue. Because when I browse Default Web Site on IIS, either http or https, it is not giving me the IIS(Internet Information Services) page that it does when it is working correctly.
I tried the above expecting that it would resolve the issue and pop up will disappear but none of it worked.

Solution: there are two approaches to fix this.

Uninstall the updates after which pop up started appearing and turn off future updates.
I prefer this solution. If you right click Default Web Site, go to Manage Settings. You will see that Start is highlighted. Due to the updates, port 80 is being used somewhere so IIS is unable to use that. Just change the http port i Bindings from 80 to 8090 or any other you prefer and start the Default Web Site. Now to make sure site is accessible, browse it and you will see the pop up is now gone and site is back to normal.


The rule of this site is to post and accept your own answer below, not lingering in comments. Besides, "Due to the updates, port 80 is being used somewhere so IIS is unable to use that" requires further digging (and there are ways), but if you don't mind moving the site to another port you can accept your own answer.
